# Split leather is created from the corium left once the top-grain has been separated from the hide, known as the drop split

Tags: meaning-in-context

Could someone confirm if "left" in the following [paragraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leather) means "to have as a result, consequence, or remainder" and not "of, relating to, directed toward, or located on the left side".
Thanks!

"Split leather is created from the corium left once the top-grain has been separated from the hide, known as the drop split."

(It seems "drop split" refers to "split leather"and not "the top-grain" ... a bit confusing)

Comment: In that case it should be, "Split leather, also known as drop split, is created from the corium left once the top-grain has been separated from the hide."

Comment: I would certainly understand it to mean _left over_, not _on the left side_.

Comment: From leather-dictionary.com: If a skin is divided into several layers over the entire surface, this process is called "splitting". Thicker leather, mostly cow leather, which is 5 to 10 millimetres thick, is split. The obtained layers are designated as grain split or top-grain split and flesh split. Sometimes, the leather is thick enough for a middle split. The split, separated from the grain split, is also called drop split.